# Why my React JS Material Table cell update is not being rendered on to the UI but can see the update in the store and on console

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have just tried to implement the basic example provided in the material table official documentation.
When I click on edit and try to change any field data, the data inside the variable and store are getting updated but it is not being displayed on the screen after we click on save and the page renders. Can anyone please advise what am I missing here??
Below is the code:

```
function StringValidation() {
  const [data,setData] = useState();
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="String Validation Preview"
      columns={[
        {
          title: 'Name', field: 'name', validate: rowData => rowData.name === '' ? 'Name cannot be empty' : '',
        },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname', validate: rowData => rowData.surname.length < 2 ? 'Surame must be have 3 chars' : '', },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric', validate: rowData => rowData.birthYear < 1900 ? 'Birthyear must be after 1900' : '', },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        ]}
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: newData =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setData([...data, newData]);
              resolve();
            }, 1000)
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              const dataUpdate = [...data];
              const index = oldData.tableData.id;
              dataUpdate[index] = newData;
              setData(dataUpdate);

              resolve();
            }, 1000)
          }),
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: What is ```setData``` in your case? I think you will need to create ```useState``` variable ```data``` and pass it as a prop to Material Table. Then, when you call ```setData``` it will re-render the table

Comment: yes, setData is the setter method of the useState for 'data'. yet its still the same behavior

Comment: See where you have a prop ```data``` for the Material Table? Replace that with ```data={data}```